# using std::sort and std::next_permutation

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have the following code which i wrote and works perfectly. I just have trouble understanding why it works. More specifically, why must we first sort the array in order to use std::next_permutation, can it not start from any configuration ?

And the part which bothers me the most is that I don't understand why we must write
sort(sides, sides+3) and next_permutation(sides, sides+3) why the "+3"! because I have three elements in the array ? What if i was using an arbitrary number of elements ?

```
bool valid(int sides[], ofstream &outfile)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(; i < 3; i++) {
    if(sides[i] <= 0) {
      outfile << "This is not a valid triangle because it\n "
              << "contains negative sides or contains a\n"
              << "side length of 0\n\n";
      return false;
    }
  }

  do{
    std::sort(sides,sides+3);
    if(sides[0] + sides[1] > sides[2])
      ;
    else{
      outfile << "This is not a valid triangle because "
              << sides[0] << " + " << sides[1]
              << " is not greater than " << sides[2];
      return false;
    }
  }while(std::next_permutation(sides,sides+3));

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Define "works".  It goes into an infinite loop for all valid triangles except equilateral triangles.  Doesn't sound like a working function to me.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley are you sure ? I just entered 7 7 7 in to stream and it the bool function valid printed 1(true).

Comment: That's an equilateral triangle. Try a non equilateral triangle, like 5 6 7.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley oh wow, thanks for pointing that out. Why isn't it working for non-equilateral triangles ?

Comment: Well, it happens to work with equilateral triangles because there is only one valid permutation, so the call to `next_permutation` returns false, because there is no next permutation.  This means the loop only executes once.  non-equilateral triangles have multiple permutations, so `next_permutation` on a sorted one returns true.  Then the triangle is sorted again at the top of the loop, and `next_permutation` gets called on the same sorted array, so of course it's going to return true every time.  So the question is, why is the call to `next_permutation` even there? Why is this even a loop?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley oh, i see, i'm re-sorting the array every single time through the loop, is that what you're saying ?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the things I'm saying.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ok, by moving the sort outside of the loop. It will work. I understand what you mean, it's not necessary to put this in the loop because if i test 5 + 6, later in the permutation i test 6 + 5 which is not necessary. All i need is a 2 or 3 if-else statements i guess.

Comment: You only need 1 if/else statement.  The one you have now is fine, just delete the opening and closing of the loop, including the call to `next_permutation`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ah...ok, i see what you're doing there. after the array is sorted, if the sum of the first two elements in the array is greater than the third element, then it must be the case that every other permutation will automatically work. In other words, sorting the array gives us a < b < c then it will always be true that a + c > b and a b + c > a

Comment: Yes. I was about to come back and comment something like that, but you figured it out. Although what you said in that last sentence is not quite correct. Rather: Sorting the array gives us `a <= b <= c`, then *if* `a + b > c`, then it must be true that `a + c > b` and `b + c > a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euclidian geometry tells us that: 
the sum of two sides is **always** greater than the remaining side

> Lets take a triangle ABC.
>   AB = 3
>   BC = 5
>   AC = 4

std::sort will sort the sides into ascending order. So that the array will contain the shorter sides first.

> *after sort*
>   side[0] = AB = 3
>   side[1] = AC = 4
>   side[2] = BC = 5

std::next_permutation returns the next possible combination of the sides.For instance:

> AC = 3
>   BC = 5
>   AB = 4

A quick example:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::next_permutation, std::sort

int main () {
  int myints[] = {1,2,3};

  std::sort (myints,myints+3);

  std::cout << "The 3! possible permutations with 3 elements:\n";

  while ( std::next_permutation(myints,myints+3) )
  {
    std::cout << myints[0] << ' ' << myints[1];
    std::cout << ' ' << myints[2] << '\n';
  }

  std::cout << "After loop: " << myints[0] << ' ';
  std::cout << myints[1] << ' ' << myints[2] << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Further reading: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/

Comment: I know that, my do-while loop returns false as soon as it discovers that the sum of two sides is not greater than the remaining side.

Answer (score 2):

the std::next_permutation documentation

> Transform range to next permutation Rearranges the elements in the
>   range [first,last) into the next lexicographically greater
>   permutation.

so unless you start sorted you won't go through all permutations

So if you start with

> 1,2,3

that last permutation would be

> 3,2,1

if you start from

> 3,1,2

only one more permutation will be found and not all

Comment: Thanks for explaining that part, sorry I couldn't really understand the documentation. I did try and read it before I came here. But now I know what it means. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the results of `std::next_permuntation` when you don't sort it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

enum class sort { no, yes };

void show_permutations(std::string s, sort option) {
  if (sort::yes == option) {
    std::sort(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
  }

  do {
    std::cout << s << '\n';
  } while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(s), std::end(s)));
}

int main() {
  show_permutations("3412", sort::yes);

  std::cout << "Now without sorting...\n";

  show_permutations("3412", sort::no);
}
```

Examine the output to see if you notice anything interesting:

```
1234
1243
1324
1342
1423
1432
2134
2143
2314
2341
2413
2431
3124
3142
3214
3241
3412
3421
4123
4132
4213
4231
4312
4321
Now without sorting...
3412
3421
4123
4132
4213
4231
4312
4321
```

The sequence created without sorting is the same as just the very end of the sequence created with sorting. What does that imply about the importance of the input's ordering?

---

What do you think would happen if you put the sorting code inside the loop?

```
void show_permutations(std::string s, sort option) {
  do {

    if (sort::yes == option) {
      std::sort(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
    }

    std::cout << s << '\n';
  } while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(s), std::end(s)));
}
```

Notice that your program sorts the triangle sides inside the `next_permutation` loop similar to this code sorting the input string inside the loop.